# How to show/hide li tag based on condition in Angular 6

Tags: angular, angular6

Hi I am using the unsorted list for showing the some links and other data, I want one of the li to be displayed based on variable value (if its true show li tag and if false then li should be hidden).

```
 <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
    <li><a style="display: flex"><span class="pr-10">Email alerts</span><ui-switch labelOn="On" labelOff="Off" switchColor="#f1f1f1" size="small" [checked]="user.EmailSubscription" (change)="onEmailSwitchChange($event)"></ui-switch></a></li>
    <li><a href="./assets/FAQs.pdf" target="_blank">FAQ</a></li>
    <li><a>Welcome, {{currentUser}}</a></li>
    <li><button type="button" style="padding-top: 14px;" class="btn btn-link" (click)="openModal(LogoutConfirm)" > Logout </button></li>
  </ul>
```

In above code I want first li tag be shown based on condition. Below is its file code:

```
 showEmailToggle:boolean;
if(sessionStorage.getItem("Role") === "Admin")
{
  this.showEmailToggle = false;
}
else
{
  this.showEmailToggle = true;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `ngIf` directive inside `ng-container` and put the `li` tag inside it

```
<ng-container *ngIf="checkSession()">

     <li><a style="display: flex"><span class="pr-10">Email alerts</span><ui-switch labelOn="On" labelOff="Off" switchColor="#f1f1f1" size="small" [checked]="user.EmailSubscription" (change)="onEmailSwitchChange($event)"></ui-switch></a></li>

</ng-container>

checkSession(){
  if(sessionStorage.getItem("Role") === "Admin")  return  false; 
  return true
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use

```
<li [style.visibility]="showEmailToggle ? 'visible' : 'hidden'"></li>
```